# Проблема с зацикливанием анимации

Tags: unity3d

луп тайм отключен, в параметрах аниматора вроде все, как надо. но анимация зацикливается. точнее даже, не доходит до конца, а все время начинается сначала. isDead срабатывает корректно. Как я понимаю, проблема либо где то в коде, либо в аниматоре. Но в аниматоре условие к анимации смерти стоит "isDead == true". вот код

```
if (isDead == true)                                     //dead
    {
        anim.SetBool("isDead", true);
    }

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        Destroy(heart);
        
        isDead = true;
       
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Сделай выход из анимации Dead в пустышку в графе анимаций.

Comment: делал выход. и в exit и в пустышку. не помогло

Comment: Если делать в exit, аниматор снова входит в start. Еще используй не bool, а trigger, что бы состояния не оставались.

Comment: я и в пустышку пробовал - не помогло. анимация все равно начинается сначала, даже не завершившись. в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: сделал по триггеру. спасибо!